Product $f=gh$ is Lipschitz, what about $g$?
Given two functions $g,h$, such that their product $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ is Lipschitz of constant $L_f$. Suppose we know that $h$ is Lipschitz too, what can be said about $g$?
From the following (very) sketched idea,it seems that Lipschitzness of the product induces boundedness of $g$, what should be the formal way of proceeding?
$$
(L_f|x-y|\geq)|f(x)-f(y)| = |g(x)h(x)-g(y)h(y)|
\\= |g(x)h(x)-g(y)h(x) + g(y)h(x) - g(y)h(y)| 
\\ \leq |g(x)-g(y)||h(x)| + |h(x)-h(y)||g(x)| 
\\ \leq |g(x)-g(y)||h(x)| + L_h|g(x)||x-y| \overset{?}{\leq} (\cdots)|x-y|
$$

$f=h=0,g$ any function.

Or $f=1, g=e^{x^2}, h=e^{-x^2}$.

I see, thank you both.
